# Vue axios doesnt change header

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am quite new to vue and I am trying to send a request to my api using axios. 
I build an interceptor which seems to work (logging is happening)

```
export default function setup() {
    console.log('Http interceptor starting...')
    Axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
        const token = store.getters.token;
        if (token) {
            request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        console.log(request);
        return request
    }, (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

If I check the console I can see the request including the token. If I check my network tab in the browser i can see the same request without the token. If I check the console of my api the token is null. Any Ideas?

Edit: If I use postman with the same request and the same token it is working as it shuld

Comment: Is this a same-origin or cross-origin request? Is the request you see in the Network tab a CORS preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: Its cross Origin. I only use the normal firefox network tab to check the request

Comment: Sure, the normal Firefox Network tab is the right place to be looking. My question was is the request a preflight OPTIONS request? If you check the request method is it `OPTIONS`, rather than, e.g., `GET` or `POST`? Also, do you get an error message in the console about a CORS preflight request failing?

Comment: Oh yeah its a Option request and i get the cross origin preflight error in the console

Comment: The `Authorization` header won't be included on the preflight request, that's normal. I suggest you do some background reading about CORS. e.g. https://cors-errors.info/faq or https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/